# How to use Cauchy's Estimates

Tags: complex-analysis

Say $f$ is an entire function and there exists some constants $K > 0$ and $R > 0$, and an integer $n \geq 1$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq K\lvert z \rvert ^n$ for all $\lvert z \rvert > R$, and I want to use Cauchy's Estimates on the disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Then I *think* we have: $\lvert f'(0) \rvert \leq \frac{K |z|^n}{R^1} = \frac{K R^n}{R}$.

But what if $f$ is an entire function and there exists some constants $K > 0$ and $R > 0$, and an integer $n \geq 1$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq K\lvert z \rvert ^n$ for all $\lvert z \rvert < R$? The only difference is the last part "for all $|z| < R$" instead of "for all $|z| > R$." Then do we still have: $\lvert f'(0) \rvert \leq \frac{K |z|^n}{R^1} = \frac{K R^n}{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy's formula
$$
f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int_{|\zeta|=r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^2}\,d\zeta.
$$
Then, if $r<R$
$$
|f'(0)|\le\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\,(K\,r^n)\Bigl(\frac{1}{r^2}\Bigr)\,(2\,\pi\,r)=K\,r^{n-1}.
$$
Since this holds for all $r<R$, it holds also for $r=R$.

Comment: Does this also hold for $r > R$?

Comment: The hypothesis is $|f(z)|\le K\,|z|^n$ for $|z|<R$. So the answer is no in general, since we do not know what happens when $|z|>R$.

Comment: So in the first part of my original post, is the application of Cauchy's Estimates incorrect since we have $|z| > R$?

Comment: No. In the first part you get $|f'(0)|\le K\,r^{n-1}$ for all $r>R$; his implies the inequality for $r=R$. In the second part you get $|f'(0)|\le K\,r^{n-1}$ for all $0<r<R$; this implies the inequality for $r=R$. But my guess is that you do not really want the inequality for $R$. You want it for all $r>R$.